# How to set a particular JRE version as default for my Java application running on JBoss

Tags: java, performance, jboss, jboss5.x

I have a Java application which runs on JBoss 5.1.0 GA. The problem I am facing is, every client machine has multiple JRE versions installed and due to several constraints, my application specifically needs JRE 1.6.33 to run smoothly. Is there a way to set default JRE version for my application in JBoss or any other settings elsewhere?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure JBoss uses the JAVA_HOME env. variable so it has to point to JRE 1.6.33.

If it's set to a different JRE you can change your starting script so it changes the JAVA_HOME to JRE1.6, starts jboss and after that it changes JAVA_HOME back to it's original value.

Comment: confirmed - it uses %JAVA_HOME% (in windows) for its JRE